# Meteor app as front end to externally updated mongo database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to set up an app that will act as a front end to an externally updated mongo database. The data will be pushed into the database by another process.

I so far have the app connecting to the external mongo instance and pulling data out with on issues, but its not reactive (not seeing any of the new data going into the mongo database).

I've done some digging and it so far can only find that I might need to set up replica sets and use oplog, is there a way to do this without going to replica sets (or is that the best way anyway)?

The code so far is really simple, a single collection, a single publication (pulling out the last 10 records from the database) and a single template just displaying that data.

No deps that I've written (not sure if that's what I'm missing).

Thanks.

Comment: Please add a code snippets. Make sure you declared the collection inside common directory..

Comment: Code on github:  https://github.com/pnunn/wfdb.git

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use Oplog? For what I've read it is the recommended approach even if your DB isn't updated by an external process, and a must if it does.

Nevertheless, without Oplog your app should see the changes on the DB made by the external process anyway. It should take longer (up to 10 seconds), but it should update.

Comment: Thanks canotto90. No reason not to use Oplog I guess, but the app never sees the changes. There is new data going into the mongo db every minute, but the app never picks it up.